# C-printing a histogram

Tags: c, histogram

This is a question from K&R:-

Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input.It is easy to draw the histogram with bars horizontal; but a vertical orientation is more challenging.

I am not supposed to use any library functions because this is only a tutorial introduction!

I have written the following program to do so but it have some bugs:-

1)If there is more than one white-space character between words, the program doesn't work as expected.

2)How do I know the maximum value of 'k' I mean how to know how many words are there in the input?

Here is the code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_WORDS 100

int main(void)
{
    int c, i=0, k=1, ch[MAX_WORDS] = {0};

    printf("enter the words:-\n");

    do
    {
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
            if(c=='\n' || c==' ' || c=='\t')
                break;
            else
                ch[i]++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while(i<MAX_WORDS);

    do
    {
        printf("%3d|",k);
        for(int j=1;j<=ch[k];j++)
            printf("%c",'*');
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }
    while(k<10);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program will work fine even if there are more than one newline characters in between the two words and `numWords` will give you the numbers of words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch, cha[100] = {0}, k = 1;
    int numWords = 0;
    int numLetters = 0;
    bool prevWasANewline = true;     //Newlines at beginning are ignored

    printf("Enter the words:-\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
            prevWasANewline = true;  //Newlines at the end are ignored
        else
        {
             if (prevWasANewline)     //Extra nelines between two words ignored
             {
                  numWords++;
                  numLetters = 0; 
             }
             prevWasANewline = false;
             cha[numWords] = ++numLetters; 
        }

    }

    do
    {
        printf("%3d|",k);
        for(int j=0;j<cha[k];j++)
            printf("%c",'*');
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    } while(k <= numWords);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who the hell downvoted this. At least he/she should have leave a comment.

Comment: The program is correct, but I don't think the program meets the requirements of K&R execise.. You're suppose to be getting counting the frequency of lengths. So if you have 5 words  such as   ' a a a a a' you'll get back  1: 5, or if you have  3 words such as - ' a ab abc' , you get back 1:1  2:1   3:1.    Thus the length : frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of an old thread, but i had the same problem. The code above works like charm, but its kind of an overkill for the knowledge we have with K&R in the first 20 pages.
I had no idea what they meant by histogram printing and that code helped me with that.
Anyway i wrote a code myself with the knowledge i gained through the book, i hope it will be helpful to someone.
Forgive me if its a bit messy, i am just a beginner myself :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YES 1
#define NO 0

int main(void)
{
    int wnumb [100];
    int i, inword, c, n, k;
    n = (-1);
    for (i = 0; i <=100; ++i) {
        wnumb [i] = 0;
    }
    inword = NO;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ( c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' ) {
            inword = NO;
        }           
        else if (inword == NO) {
            ++n;
            ++wnumb [n];
            inword = YES;
        }
        else {
            ++wnumb [n];
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
        if (wnumb [i] > 0) {
            printf ("\n%3d. | ", (i+1));
            for (k = 1; k <= wnumb[i]; ++k) {
                printf("*");
            }
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of simple Histogram(Vertically)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, j, max;
    int ndigit[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];

    max = ndigit[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 10; ++i)        /* for Y-axis */
        if (max < ndigit[i])
            max = ndigit[i];

    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (i = max; i > 0; --i) {
        printf("%.3d|", i);
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            (ndigit[j] >= i) ? printf(" X ") : printf("   ");
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("   ");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)        /* for X-axis */
        printf("%3d", i);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```